# equal types not be assigned — why

Tags: typescript, option-type

I am trying to get my head around a simple Monad / Option / Maybe implementation and I am just asking myself how get the same interface for Lists and single values.

```
type ItemType<T> = T extends (infer B)[] ? B : T;

interface Option<T, R = ItemType<T>> {
    map: <U>(fx: (v: R) => Option<U>) => Option<U>;
}

class Some<T> implements Option<T> {

    constructor(
        private readonly val: T
    ){}

    map <U>(fx: (v: T) => Option<U>): Option<U> {
        return fx(this.val)
    }
}

class List<T> implements Option<T[]> {

    constructor(
        private readonly items: T[]
    ){}

    map <U>(fx: (v: T) => Option<U>): Option<U> {
        // should be for each element in the list
        return fx(this.items[0])
    }
}
```

But as one can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAq4IB4kD4oF4pKggA94A7AEwGcoAKAS1IDMIAnKAIQEoBtAXSgD8HKAC58AbgBQ0hvBaMAhgGNoAeTDA6Ae1IYANFABKuWPGSoMmbAG9JUe1AQKwYtAFVMNRkTE0AbmKGnLjY6po67pjBOKEa2roeUgC+0koANgqU1ADKWgjoWFB0CGBpiBCkwNRh8ZZQtnYOSjqUwCwArkrAWiw0jQ4OYCx0fgrwUCwQCuQ6aSBQo2liSP1QnNYpq05gUJFePrQB+NGx4QlRYjURHvWrA5PA7SykUN40wAAWdJQAdIucqxSm3SmWoABlvsA6sVSuVKtU4hEkHwbNIBs1SK0Ol0en0BgMhiMxtBJtNZvM6GZKMs+Kt1psBttdh59r4jkgTlArudOJdEedbviHA8ni83p9vj9KYhKNwAAy8AEDIHSIA) that does not work for `class Some<T>` since typescript says:

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ItemType'.

Comment: Can't you have something like `Option<number, string>` if you explicitly type it? I'm not sure how you ensure that `R` is assignable to `T` or vice versa.

Comment: No, It should be generic

Comment: Check fp-ts source code.